# Wrong datatime index in Pandas DataFrame with class

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a Pandas DataFrame with and without class. In case of class I have wrong datatime index but if no class it is ok. Please help.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


class Records:
    def __init__(self):
        columns = ['moment', 'val']

        # Create an empty DataFrame with columns
        self.dfv = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

    def add(self, moment, val):

        # Record
        rec = {'moment': moment, 'val': val}

        # Convert 'moment' to datetime
        rec['moment'] = pd.to_datetime(rec['moment'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        # Add the record to DataFrame
        self.dfv = self.dfv.append(rec, ignore_index=True)

        self.dfv['moment'] = pd.to_datetime(self.dfv['moment'])
        self.dfv.set_index('moment', inplace=True)

        return self.dfv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('=============================Class records===================')
    r = Records()

    df = r.add('2023-11-01 10:00:00', 100.0)
    print(df)
    df = r.add('2023-11-01 11:00:00', 120.0)

    # Print the updated DataFrame
    print(df)
    df.info()

    print('=============================Single records==================')
    # Test first column datatime as an index

    columns = ['moment', 'val']
    dfv = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
    dfv['moment'] = pd.to_datetime(dfv['moment'])
    dfv.set_index('moment', inplace=True)

    rec = {'moment': '2023-11-01 10:00:00', 'val': 100.0}

    # Convert 'moment' to datetime
    rec['moment'] = pd.to_datetime(rec['moment'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    # Add the record to DataFrame
    dfv = dfv.append(rec, ignore_index=True)

    # Set 'moment' as the index
    rec2 = {'moment': '2023-11-01 11:00:00', 'val': 120.0}
    dfv = dfv.append(rec2, ignore_index=True)

    # Set 'moment' as the index
    dfv.set_index('moment', inplace=True)

    print(dfv)
    dfv.info()
    exit(0)
```

an output

```
=============================Class records===================
                       val
moment                    
2023-11-01 10:00:00  100.0
                       val
moment                    
NaT                  100.0
2023-11-01 11:00:00  120.0
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 2 entries, NaT to 2023-11-01 11:00:00
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   val     2 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 32.0 bytes
=============================Single records==================
                       val
moment                    
2023-11-01 10:00:00  100.0
2023-11-01 11:00:00  120.0
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 2 entries, 2023-11-01 10:00:00 to 2023-11-01 11:00:00
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   val     2 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 32.0+ bytes
```

So with no class I have exactly what I want to get but if I use class (and I need to use class for my purposes) I have NaT as a first record index value . Please advise how to have a correct code with class. Thanks.

Comment: Your code can't work with recent versions of Pandas because `append` method was removed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `df` has a different shape after the first time you call `r.add(...)`. Let's print `df` after initialization and after the first call to see this clearly:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('=============================Class records===================')
    r = Records()

    df = r.dfv
    print("""df after initialization:\n""")
    print(df)
    
    df = r.add('2023-11-01 10:00:00', 100.0)
    print("""df after first `add` call:\n""")
    print(df)

=============================Class records===================
df after initialization:

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [moment, val]
Index: []

df after first `add` call:

                       val
moment                    
2023-11-01 10:00:00  100.0
...\2699656422.py:20: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  self.dfv = self.dfv.append(rec, ignore_index=True)
```

So, your first call is working because you are using [`df.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.4/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) on a `df` that has 2 columns (`['moment', 'val']`). Yet, with all subsequent calls, your `df` has only 1 column left (`['val']`), with `moment` having become the `index`.

The fix would be to initialize the `df` with `'moment'` as the index, and then also to get the incoming data in this same shape before adding it. Note the `FutureWarning` in our output above: `df.append` is deprecated since version 1.4.0, so let's use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) instead.

```py
import pandas as pd

class Records:
    def __init__(self):

        # Create an empty DataFrame with a `DatetimeIndex`
        self.dfv = pd.DataFrame(columns=['val'],
                                index=pd.DatetimeIndex([], name='moment'))

    def add(self, moment, val):

        # Record (changing to setup of your dict)
        rec = {'val': {pd.to_datetime(moment): val}}

        # Add the record to DataFrame (using `pd.concat`)
        self.dfv = pd.concat([self.dfv, 
                              pd.DataFrame(rec).rename_axis('moment')])
        
        return self.dfv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('=============================Class records===================')
    r = Records()

    df = r.dfv
    print(f"""df after initialization:\n\n{df}""")

    df = r.add('2023-11-01 10:00:00', 100.0)
    print(f"""\ndf after first `add` call:\n\n{df}""")

    df = r.add('2023-11-01 11:00:00', 120.0)
    print(f"""\ndf after second `add` call:\n\n{df}""")
```

Output:

```py
=============================Class records===================
df after initialization:

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [val]
Index: []

df after first `add` call:

                       val
moment                    
2023-11-01 10:00:00  100.0

df after second `add` call:

                       val
moment                    
2023-11-01 10:00:00  100.0
2023-11-01 11:00:00  120.0
```

Comment: Your code raises a `FutureWarning` on most recent versions of Pandas. Look at my answer regarding dataframe initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your code with:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


class Records:
    def __init__(self):
        # Create a correctly typed dataframe
        self.dfv = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.Series(name='val', dtype='float'),
                                index=pd.DatetimeIndex([], name='moment'))

    def add(self, moment, val):
        # Same remark as previous
        moment = pd.to_datetime(moment, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        rec = pd.DataFrame({'val': val}, index=[moment])
        # Safe concat, works with most recent versions of Pandas
        self.dfv = pd.concat([self.dfv, rec], axis=0)
        return self.dfv


print('=============================Class records===================')
r = Records()

df = r.add('2023-11-01 10:00:00', 100.0)
print(df)

df = r.add('2023-11-01 11:00:00', 120.0)
print(df)

df.info()
```

Output:

```
=============================Class records===================
                       val
2023-11-01 10:00:00  100.0
                       val
2023-11-01 10:00:00  100.0
2023-11-01 11:00:00  120.0
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 2 entries, 2023-11-01 10:00:00 to 2023-11-01 11:00:00
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   val     2 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 32.0 bytes
```